# Error in mathematica. Setdelayed: Tag Plus in

Tags: compiler-errors, wolfram-mathematica

I am new in mathematica and i don´t understand why appear the following message:

Setdelayed: Tag Plus in ... [$\theta$,r]is protected.

When i am try to define the field:

F11[[Theta]*, r*] =  -( r^2 [Alpha]120 Cos[[Theta]]^3 + r Cos[[Theta]]^2 ([Alpha]110 +
r ([Alpha]111 + [Beta]120) Sin[[Theta]]) +  Sin[[Theta]] ([Beta]100 + r Sin[[Theta]] ([Beta]101 + r [Beta]102 Sin[[Theta]])) + Cos[[Theta]] ([Alpha]100 + r Sin[[Theta]] ([Alpha]101 + [Beta]110 + r ([Alpha]102 + [Beta]111) Sin[[Theta]])))

Can they help me? please. Thanks.

Comment: It is difficult to tell, but it is possible that you previously assigned a value to θ or r and that is causing the problem. Try `Clear[θ,r];F11[θ_,r_]:= -(r^2 α...)` and then try `F11[2,3]` and see if it gives a good result